# How does position in Threejs work exactly?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make something responsive in Threejs which will be full screen.
I am having a hard time understanding the concept of positioning of objects due to this.
I will also want to add animations so need the positions to be dynamic.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var materialRed = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var materialBlue = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );

var circle = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CircleGeometry( 12, 128 ), materialRed );
scene.add(circle);

var square = [];
square.push( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10, 1), materialBlue ) );
square.push( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10, 1), materialBlue ) );
scene.add(square[0]);
scene.add(square[1]);
square[0].position.x = 100;
square[1].position.x = -100;

camera.position.z = 100;

var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    circle.position.x += 0.1;
    circle.position.y += 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.min.js"></script>
```

```
var circle = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CircleGeometry( 12, 128 ), materialRed );
scene.add(circle);
circle.position.x = 100;
```

I need to understand how positioning will change with change in aspect ration and camera frustums.

**EDIT**

For eg-

I need to move the sphere in an elliptical orbit around the screen. I need to calculate the equation of the orbit which will get me position of the sphere at every instance. I don't want the sphere to move out of frame and for that I'm ready to change the length of axes or size of sphere.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your question, an example probably ?

Comment: Essentially I could also frame it as how is position in three.js related to `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerheight`

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713945/changing-proportionally-the-size-of-a-geometry-when-the-window-size-changes-usin/). The answer gets into how the camera fov works and techniques on how to handle resizes

Comment: You can change camera position  and FOV with respect to canvas size.